# IllegalAccessException for JFXTextField with java sdk 12

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

I added  JFXTextField in my javafx application but I got this error with no clue how to solve it

> class com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTextFieldSkin (in module com.jfoenix) cannot access a member of class javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin (in module javafx.controls) with modifiers "private"

Controller :

```
package sample;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Button clickMe;


@FXML
private JFXButton materialButton;

@FXML
private JFXTextField textField;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    materialButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
        {
            String text = textField.getText().trim();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fcda;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="clickMe" layoutX="198.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="225.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fffe;" text="Click Me" textFill="#722929" />
      <JFXButton fx:id="materialButton" layoutX="231.0" layoutY="82.0" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="139.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffff;" textFill="#280c0c">
         <font>
            <Font size="25.0" />
         </font></JFXButton>
      <JFXTextField fx:id="textField" layoutX="233.0" layoutY="24.0" promptText="Enter UserName" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Which jfoenix version are you using?

Comment: i'm using version 9.0.8 @JoséPereda

Comment: You should be able to workaround this specific case with `--add-opens javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin=com.jfoenix` to open the javafx.scene.control.skin package for deep reflection by code in module com.jfoenix. However, that's just a workaround until the maintainers of this library fix their issues.

Answer (score 13):

This issue has already been reported at the JFoenix's issue tracker:

- [JDK 12 incompatible](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/955)
- [IllegalAccessException for JFXTextField / JFXPasswordField with JDK12](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/986)

For starters, JFoenix is not really ready for Java 11+. The released version is intended for Java 9, but it still works with Java 11 and JavaFX 11, providing you add the JavaFX dependencies.

However, under JDK 12 it fails to run, and the issue is not JavaFX related: even with JavaFX 11.0.2 it still fails.

The issue is related to the use of [reflection](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/JFoenix-9.0.0/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/skins/JFXTextFieldSkin.java#L59) to access the `Text` node of `TextFieldSkin`:

```
textNode = ReflectionHelper.getFieldContent(TextFieldSkin.class, this, "textNode");
```

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.jfoenix.adapters.ReflectionHelper (in module com.jfoenix) cannot access a member of class javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin (in module javafx.controls) with modifiers "private"
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:355)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:639)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkAccess(Field.java:1075)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:416)
        at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.adapters.ReflectionHelper.getFieldContent(ReflectionHelper.java:98)
        at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTextFieldSkin.<init>(JFXTextFieldSkin.java:59)
```

While this worked fine up until Java 11.0.2, with Java 12 <s>a [regression](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221530)</s> recent changes in `unsafe` prevents this from working, and causes `textNode = null`.

As @AlanBateman mentions in his comments below:

> [The JFoenix maintainers] should replace their `setAccessible` method to call `obj.setAccessible(true)` so that the user gets the right exceptions when the library tries to hack internals that are not accessible to it. If you do that then the user can workaround those issues with `--add-exports` or `--add-opens` options until the maintainers of the library fix their issues.

For now this will mean sticking to JDK 11.

Alternatively, you could try to build your own JFoenix version, cloning the repo (branch 9.0.0) and making the necessary changes to make it work with JavaFX 11+ (out of scope of this answer...), and removing the use of reflection where possible.

For instance, the `textNode` can be directly retrieved with:

```
textNode = textPane.getChildren().get(1);
```

or, still rely on reflection, but with the proper changes mentioned:

```
try {
    Field field = cls.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true); // <-- Use this.
    return (T) field.get(obj);
} catch (Throwable ex) { }
```

combined with:

```
--add-exports=javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin=$moduleName
```

Comment: Not clear why JDK-8221530 is referenced here - that issue is about JNI code with no java frames on the stack trying to invoke caller sensitive methods. In the above, it looks like there are java stack frames.

Comment: @AlanBateman I'm trying to find a release note that explains the difference between JDK 11.0.2 and 12.0.1, related to `reflection` and/or `unsafe`. This is the [line](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/JFoenix-9.0.0/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/adapters/ReflectionHelper.java#L53) that doesn't work now. Any hint?

Comment: If I read that code correctly then it's trying to use Unsafe to hack a private/undocumented field in java.lang.reflect.Field. That hack does not work on recent JDK releases. They should replace their setAccessible method to call obj.setAccessible(true) so that the user gets the right exceptions when the library tries to hack internals that are not accessible to it. If you do that then the user can workaround those issues with --add-exports or --add-opens options until the maintainers of the library fix their issues.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what they are doing, and your comment makes total sense, but that's up to them. You mentioned "recent JDK releases", but the hack still works on 11.0.2, so I was wondering what did change (so I can add it to my answer).

Comment: The JDK hides a number of very security sensitive private fields from core reflection. The private fields in jlr.Field were added to that list in JDK 12. This is something the JFoenix maintainers need to fix as it's ridiculous to be depending on hacks like this.

Comment: @AlanBateman Thanks, I've edited my answer according to your comments.

Comment: It's already been fixed with JFoenix 9.0.10 so that it is now compatible with Java 11+.