# Getting error when using Jfoenix 9 controls with JDK 13

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix, java-13

Here is the code that causes the problem

```
<JFXColorPicker layoutX="109.0" layoutY="282.0" />
        <JFXCheckBox layoutX="58.0" layoutY="356.0" />
        <JFXNodesList layoutX="87.0" layoutY="307.0" />
```

Here is the error

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.jfoenix.controls.behavior.JFXGenericPickerBehavior (in unnamed module @0x3be7d920) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ComboBoxBaseBehavior (in module javafx.controls) because module javafx.controls does not export com.sun.javafx
```

I am very new to Java and developing so if this a stupid error or me just not knowing enough then I apologize. In intellij I added the Jfoenix .jar file to the libraries, but i'm not sure what else to do to correct this. If i could be pointed in the correct direction then I would appreciate it. If i need to go to a lower JDK, is there another download location? the one on the oracle site doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Hi, could you edit your question and add the code that causes the problem please?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. Instead, copy-and-paste the text into the question itself.

Comment: ok i found the code that causes the issue and added it, but i'm not sure how to edit my question. I followed a youtube video for setting up Jfeonix with intellij and followed it exactly.

Comment: i will fix that as well

Comment: Is that formatted correctly now? I'm new and apologize again.

Comment: In this case the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/6395627) provides enough information, but it's typically best to provide the entire stack trace (including all the `at ...` lines). As for your problem, check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/53037442/6395627. If you don't have JFoenix on the moduelpath (as your error message suggests) then replace `com.jfoenix` with `ALL-UNNAMED` in the `--add-exports` arguments.

Comment: If you're not sure what a module is, see [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Comment: Duplicated of [java.lang.IllegalAccessError with JavaFX and JFoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132710/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-with-javafx-and-jfoenix/56149247#56149247) (Maven plugin) or [NullPointerException when loading an FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226032/nullpointerexception-when-loading-an-fxml/58239676#58239676) (Gradle plugin). If you don't use build tools, find in those answers the required command line arguments that you will need to add to your project.