# JFoenix JFXTextField NullPointerException when added to my application

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

Whenever I add a JFXTextField to my application, when I try to compile it I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTextFieldSkin.updateTextPos(JFXTextFieldSkin.java:109)
    at com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTextFieldSkin.layoutChildren(JFXTextFieldSkin.java:93)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:601)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1206)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
.........
```

I don't try to use it or anything. Simply adding it. Everything else seems to work with no issues. If I were to remove it, the program compiles fine and works.

I went to [.updateTextPos()](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/skins/JFXTextFieldSkin.java), but I don't really understand what's causing it.

[I found a problem similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889654/illegalaccessexception-for-jfxtextfield-with-java-sdk-12), but the error is different. Should I do what's suggested there as well anyway? I'd rather not mess with the whole library since I don't have that much knowledge.